# How to Take Away Leading Zeros In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a math game that gives a percentage at the end of questions you got right.

I don't want any zeros I just want it to round to the nearest whole number. I don't know who to do this though.

This is the code that makes the percentage:

```
percentage = correct / questions * 100
print ("Your Correct Percentage: ", percentage, "%")
```

And the result when you get 1/3 right is:

```
Your Correct Percentage:  33.33333333333333 %
```

I want the 33.3333333333 to just round down to 33. Thank You, Andrew the Python Coder

Comment: `int(percentage)` make this change in you print statement

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard function [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

```
percentage = correct / questions * 100
print ("Your Correct Percentage: ", round(percentage), "%")
```

It also accepts a second parameter that specifies the number of decimal places to round to. For instance, if you wanted a bit more precision, say, two decimal places, use:

```
print ("Your Correct Percentage: ", round(percentage, 2), "%")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `str.format` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#formatspec)) to do it for you:

```
correct, questions = 1, 3
percentage = correct / questions * 100
print ("Your Correct Percentage: {:.2g}%".format(percentage))
#OR:
#print ("Your Correct Percentage: {:.0f}%".format(percentage))
```

Prints:

```
Your Correct Percentage: 33%
```

OR to add `%` sign automatically, without any digits after `.`:

```
correct, questions = 1, 3
print ("Your Correct Percentage: {:.0%}".format(correct / questions))
```